# Umbraco: When deleting a user, the user keeps appearing in search results

Tags: search, asp.net-membership, umbraco

I have created a Register Member usercontrol for Umbraco based on the asp.net CreateUserWizard control. This control works good because the user is created in the way I wanted. However when I delete the user from the backend in the members section, the user dissappears from the user tree but not from the search results. Is the user actually deleted and do I need to somehow also update the search index. If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Umbraco Membership provider first step I would say is to open your database and take a look in your **cmsMember** table to see if the user still exists. If they do not then you are potentially looking at a caching issue however you shouldn't really need to take any additional steps to flush the cache.

When you say search results do you mean the member search from Umbraco back-end or a custom member search? Also what version are you running?

Comment: it is the member search from Umbraco Back-end. And I do think it is a caching issue indeed. I think because I was debugging the cache was not updated as it should. However to be sure I have added an event handler when deleting a member. I needed that anyway to also delete the customer record if the member record was deleted. In that event I delete the membernode from the searchindex, just to be sure.

Comment: It depends on your Umbraco version, as well. Looking at Umbraco 6.x, the table *cmsMember* is empty, with user information instead being held in *umbracoUser*

Comment: @OwenBlacker That is incorrect, the umbracoUser table is for back office users not for public members. Be careful not to confuse the two as one is for administration of the site and the other is for site members. This is why you will find two separate membership providers in your web.config.

Comment: Aaaaaah, I thought the post was talking about back-office users (which is what I was looking up when I stumbled across this post). A useful disclaimer then, thank you @ProNotion :)

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco just disable member, and not delete it in database.
in your research request try to add the restriction on member that are activated state or state not disabled.

Comment: That is not the case if you use Member.Delete. It seems that the member search in the dashboard uses the examine searchresults. So when doing a rebuild of the Examine index the member is not found anymore.

Comment: ok, but if you get a look in database (table UnbracoUser), you will find the member with state disabled. in my case i am usin Umbraco 4.7

Comment: Not in my case. Also it is a member not user. So he is not in the umbracoUser table, but in the cmsMember table. (I am using version 6)

Comment: @BELotfi You also seem to be confusing the umbracoUser table with members. As per my comment above the umbracoUser table is for managing back office users not members.